# Python: why with open file works with subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, subprocess, with-statement

As I know, if we open a file using "with open", the file will be closed when the code reach out of the with context manager.

```
with open(somefile) as fd:
  # do some thing
  # fd.close() # automatically
print("Before We get here, the fd is closed")
```

So I don't understand why the code below works:

```
with open("hello.txt", mode="w") as fd:
    p = subprocess.Popen("ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10", stdout=fd, stderr=fd)
    # fd.close() # automatically
print("Before We get here, the fd is closed")
```

I closed the file immediately after the subprocess called, and the command ping will run for 10 seconds. Why the output of ping still can write into hello.txt successfully?
In my thought, Popen should raise exception because the fd is closed.
Any one can explain why?

Comment: The `Popen` class (see [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/80117dd45059a9dd8f2a2c9149df8f86608f0ca0/Lib/subprocess.py#L749)) creates a duplicate of the file handle. Try following [get_handles](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/80117dd45059a9dd8f2a2c9149df8f86608f0ca0/Lib/subprocess.py#L992) and you'll find [_make_inheritable](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/80117dd45059a9dd8f2a2c9149df8f86608f0ca0/Lib/subprocess.py#L1414)

Comment: Note that an external process can't use a Python file-like object anyway: the file-like object is only used to supply or create an OS-level file descriptor that can be used.

Answer (score -1):

for the subprocess
The `subprocess.Popen()` is used to start a new process and interact with it.
The function returns a `subprocess.Popen` object, which represents the new process.

the docs are here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

for the file open / close.
You can check the status at each step of the code with this:

```py
import subprocess

with open("hello.txt", mode="w") as fd:
    p = subprocess.Popen("ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10", stdout=fd, stderr=fd)
    print('file closed:', fd.closed)
    # fd.close() # automatically
print('file closed:', fd.closed)
print("Before We get here, the fd is closed")
```

which gives this:

```
file closed: False
file closed: True
Before We get here, the fd is closed
```